# Scrapy doesn't parse specific requests

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm writing a scrapy application that crawls a website main page, saves his url, and also checks for his menu items, so it would do the same process recursively, to them.

```
class NeatSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "example"
start_urls = ['https://example.com/main/']

def parse(self, response):

  url = response.url
  yield url

  # check for in-menu article links
  menu_items = response.css(MENU_BAR_LINK_ITEM).extract()
  if menu_items is not None:
    for menu_item in menu_items:
      yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(menu_item), callback=self.parse)
```

In the example website, each menu item leads to another page with another menu items.

**Some pages responses get to the 'parse' method, and so their url gets saved, while others not.
Those who are not, are giving back a 200 status (when I enter their address manually, in the browser), don't throw any exceptions, and  pretty much shows the same behavior as other pages who do get to the parse method.**

Addition Information: ALL of the menu items get to the last line in code (without any errors), and if I provide an 'errback' callback method, no request ever gets there.

**EDIT:** here is the log: http://pastebin.com/2j5HMkqN

Comment: Unless they are caught by some middleware, HTTP 200 response should be passed to the callback method you have set up in the `Request` object (or `parse()` if not set explicitly). Please provide console logs from your crawl, the especially the startup (with the enabled components), some lines showing an HTTP 200 without any sign of parsing, and the stats at the end. By the way, please correct the indentation of the spider code in your question. Also, `yield url` will not mean anything to Scrapy: it should either be `yield Request(url)` (or similar) or `yield {"url": url}`.

Comment: the code here is a little simplified then in reality, the 'yield' line itself is written in the proper syntax. Also, the page itself via browser is giving back 200 status, I'm not sure about his status in my app, as I don't get any response. I changed my original post as it was indeed, confusing. thanks.

Comment: I can suggest that you add `self.logger.debug("parsing %r" % response)` as the first statement in your callback to verify that the response is fed into `parse` and what status code you get. You could also print out `response.headers` and `reponse.body` if there's anything special about those responses.

Comment: the parser callback is never even getting triggered with those requests.

Answer (score 0):

There might be chance that the website you are scraping showing Captchas.

You can debug your scraper like this, this will open the scraped webpage in your OS default browser.

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

def parse_details(self, response):
    if "item name" not in response.body:
        open_in_browser(response)
```

Comment: @dneumark maybe menus are being loaded by AJAX/JS calls. Can you send me link of website you are scraping

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cant share the website itself. The menu, though, is not generated by JS calls. Also, most of the items at the same menu, are doing just fine.

Comment: @dneumark do this, disable JS in your browser, then open that link in browser which is not being scraped by your scraper, and then copy same selector used in your scraper, and then find items using that selector in your browser, see if it selects any items.

Comment: if it doesnt selects items, that means selector is wrong, also post your scrapy logs, and you can hide the website if you dont want to show. without logs and more info, no one will be able to help you here

Comment: Just for making sure, I debugged the code where its go through the menu, and it does manage to get the wanted address from the menu, the app actually has the right address that should work, but when it go send with the request, it's still gets no response.